# Fetch element in list in a list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I fetch element in list in a list in Groovy?

```
def x = [
[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10]
]

println x[0][1]

2
```

Comment: Looks like you have already answered your question ?

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: what does it mean `it does not work` ? do you see any error?

Comment: It does [here](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxLSU1TqFCwVYjmijbUMdIx1jHRMY3V4Yo20zHXsdCx1DE0iOWK5eIqKMrMK8nJU6iINoiNNgQKcCkgAQBBPQ93)

Comment: Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#getAt(int). is an error. When I run x.each{println it.Class} I get a class type class.java,util.ArrayList for each element.

Comment: you may want to describe the version of Groovy you are using, your environment. Nobody really wants to read your mind here

Comment: It looks problem was because I was using def x. When I put List<List> x., it works now.

Comment: no, as the groovy console shows

Comment: Is this happening some some context which has static type checking enabled? (like `@CompileStatic`)?

Comment: "no, as the groovy console shows" - @injecteer I don't think "no" is necessarily correct.  There are contexts where using `List<List> x` will allow the code to work.  OP said "When I put List<List> x., it works now." and that could be true.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have static type checking enabled.  The following will work unless you uncomment the CompileStatic annotation.

```
//@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class Demo {
    void untypedArg(list) {
        println list[0][1]
    }

    void typedArg(List list) {
        println list[0][1]
    }

    static void main(args) {
        def d = new Demo()
        def list = [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6]]
        d.untypedArg list
        d.typedArg list
    }
}
```